# Django Search Function inside ForeignKey

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a class with huge amount of data and another class which should take the title value from this class.
How can I add a search function to ForeignKey as you can see in following Image. Or does Django have a way to solve this problem? Thanks!

[image: Search inside ForeignKey]

```
class Menue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        panels = [
            FieldPanel('title', classname="col12"),
        ]
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Wochen(models.Model):
    menu_1 = models.ForeignKey(Menue,
        null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name="menu_1+")
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('menu_1', classname="col12"),
    ]
def __str__(self):
    return self.menu_1
```

opened github [issue](https://github.com/khashashin/blemmy/issues/4)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Indexing documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12/topics/search/indexing.html?highlight=indexing#wagtailsearch-indexing-models) in Wagtail and try adding something like this:

```
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import index
class Menue(index.Indexed, models.Model):
    ...
    search_fields = [
        index.SearchField('title', partial_match=True, boost=10)
    ]
```

It looks to me like this approach is supported by [WagtailModelChooser](https://github.com/takeflight/wagtailmodelchooser).